# How to run this command in a shell?

Tags: node.js, bash

For a lot of my node scripts I need to inject environment variables from a node.js script. The resulting bash command always ends up looking like this:

```
yarn workspace @nl/server dotenv -e .env.development prisma --preview-feature db seed
```

The problem here is that the `--preview-feature` flag will not be used for the `prisma` command that it was intended for. I've tried:

```
yarn workspace @nl/server dotenv -e .env.development -- prisma --preview-feature db seed
```

But it did not help. I'd love to know how I can run commands like the one above while applying the correct arguments.

Comment: setting aside for the moment how the script builds a `bash` command ... what would the 'correct' `yarn` command look like if it were manually entered it at the command prompt? at some point we'll likely need to see the actual code that generates the command; without more details I'm wondering if the script is generating `prisma --preview-feature` (as a single string) vs `prisma` `--preview-feature` (as 2 strings)

Comment: The basic command I want to run is just `prisma db seed --preview-freature`. This is a command from the Prisma ORM library for NodeJS. The command expects some env variables and I'm running it from a workspace on top of that.

Comment: All the command in an array `pr_cmd=(prisma --preview-feature db seed)` and invoke as `dotenv -e .env.development "${pr_cmd[@]}"`. Worth the try I think. Also, adding a semicolon in the middle `dotenv -e .env.development; "${pr_cmd[@]}"`

Comment: assuming you can cut-n-paste that `yarn/prisma` command at your command prompt and it works ... I would suggest updating the question with the actual code that's generating this `yarn/prisma` command (preferably a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Answer (score 0):

Use `--` to tell `yarn` to stop looking for its own options.

```
yarn workspace @nl/server dotenv -e .env.development -- prisma --preview-feature db seed
```

Comment: Thank you for your input @chepner. As the second half of my posts suggests, I've already tried this approach or am I overlooking any difference between the code you've posted and the second code block from my post?